# How to work with absolute imports when developing a package

Tags: python, import, package

It's been a while that I am struggling with imports in packages. When I develop a package, I read everywhere that it is preferable to use absolute imports in submodules of that package. I understand that and I like it more as well. But then I don't like and I also read that you shouldn't use `sys.path.append('/path/to/package')` to use your package in development...

So my question is, how do you develop such a package from zero, using directly absolute imports? At the moment I develop the package using relative imports, since then I am able to test the code I am writing before packaging and installing, then I change the imports once I have a release and build the package.

What is the correct way of doing such thing? In Pycharm for example you would mark the folder as 'source roor' and be able to work as if the package folder was in the path. Still I read that this is not the proper way... what am I missing? How do you develop a package while testing its code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mileage may vary but this is what I usually do:

Within a package (`foo`), absolute (`import foo.bar`) or relative (`import .bar`) doesn't matter to me as long as it works. Sometimes, I prefer relative especially when the project is large and one day I might decide to move a number of source files into a subdirectory.

How do I test? My `$PYTHONPATH` usually has `.` in it, and my directory hierarchy is like this:

```
/path/to/foo_project
   /setup.py
   /foo
      /__init__.py
      /bar.py
   /test
      /test1.py
      /test2.py
```

then the script in `foo_project/test/test1.py` will be like what you normally use the package, using `import foo.bar`. And when I test my code, I will be in the directory `foo_project` and run `python test/test1.py`. Since I have `.` in my `$PYTHONPATH`, it will find the directory `foo` and use it as a package.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That's indeed what I am doing as well, relative imports and then tests/scripts package folder. The problem with this approach is that I don't use absolute imports inside the package, and therefore modules in subpackages cannot access modules in other subpackages. When the hierarchy is flat as in your example, this is approach works well, but when you have subpackages absolute imports are needed. That's why I think absolute imports are preferred and suggested. So the main question remains, how do people that use absolute imports develop those packages?

Comment: Relative import still works: `import ..bar.fubar` means to look for `../bar/fubar.py`

Comment: When I try to use `..` I usually get `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. Still have to figure that out.
Anyways your answer helped me clarifying my doubts. Indeed `.` is in the `PYTHONPATH` so I can just develop the package with absolute imports, and just run `python` from the repository folder containing the package folder (`/path/to/foo_project`). The package will always be in the path and absolute imports will work. This was the point I was missing, together with the fact that Python 3 eliminated implicit relative imports. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The error might due to you didn't have `__init__.py` in the directory. Even a zero-byte file helps. It is a signal to Python that the directory is part of a package